# mousemove doesn't work only runs on click

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I wanted my website to play music when the mouse moved. To get past chromes new autoplay thing. So I set this up:

```js
 // creates an mousemove listener to the html element
   document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
 // starts audio when page loads
    myAudio.play()
      });
```

Chrome is too smart. This can never be done.

Comment: Disabling autoplay is a user experience improvement. Why do you want to circumvent this important improvement to user experience?

Comment: Chrome probably doesn't let you do that either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put focus onto `body` (or onto an element within `body`) to make it fire `mousemove`. That's why you have to click first.
So remove `body` from here `document.body.addEventListener('mousemove'...`

```js
var myAudio = new Audio('http://soundbible.com/mp3/Tyrannosaurus%20Rex%20Roar-SoundBible.com-807702404.mp3');

// creates an mousemove listener to the html element
   document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
 // starts audio when page loads
    myAudio.play()
      });
```

Comment: @leogoesger, I've tested.

Comment: I dont get why this has anything to do with `body`.

Comment: @leogoesger, I've updated my answer with working snippet and some details.

Comment: Don't think this works anymore. It requires a click.